# Issue calling a generic common repository's method

Tags: c#, oop, generics, abstract-class

I have a base repository setup.  I want to create a generic common repository to use a common method which returns a boolean called:

> DoesRecordExist()

I have the base repo and common repo setup, but i'm having issue referencing the ICommonRepository in the service.  How do I call this method?

**BaseRepository:**

```
   public abstract class BaseRepository<TModel> : IBaseRepository<TModel> where TModel : BaseClass
    {
        private readonly IDbContext _context;
        private readonly IValidator<TModel> _validator;

        public BaseRepository(IDbContext context, IValidator<TModel> validator = null)
        {
            _context = context;
            _validator = validator ?? new InlineValidator<TModel>();
        }

        public bool DoesRecordExist(Guid id)
        {
            return _context.Set<TModel>().Any(x => x.Guid == id);
        }
    }
```

**CommonRepository:**

```
 public  class CommonRepository<TModel> : BaseRepository<TModel> where TModel : BaseClass, ICommonRepository<TModel>
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private readonly IValidator<TModel> _validator;
    public CommonRepository(IDbContext context, IValidator<TModel> validator = null) : base(context, validator)
    {
        _context = context;
        _validator = validator ?? new InlineValidator<TModel>();
    }
    public bool CommonDoesRecordExist(Guid id)
    {
        return DoesRecordExist(id);
    }
}
```

**GlobalService:**

```
private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
private readonly ISubcategoryRepository _subCategoryRepository;
private readonly ISubcategoryDescriptionRepository _subcategoryDescriptionRepository;
private readonly ICommonRepository<??????> _commonRepository;

public GlobalDataService(
    ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, 
    ISubcategoryRepository subCategoryRepository, 
    ISubcategoryDescriptionRepository subcategoryDescriptionRepository, 
    ICommonRepository<????> commonRepository)
{
    _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
    _subCategoryRepository = subCategoryRepository;
    _subcategoryDescriptionRepository = subcategoryDescriptionRepository;
    _commonRepository = commonRepository;
}

 public bool DoesUserRecordExist(Guid userId)
    {
        //PROBLEM ON THIS LINE... bool existingData = _commonRepository.CommonDoesRecordExist(userId); 
            if (existingData)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
            else
            {
                //do other stuff
            }
        }
```

**ICommonRepository.cs**

```
   public interface ICommonRepository<T> : IBaseRepository
    {
        bool CommonDoesRecordExist(Guid id);
    }
```

**IBaseRepository.cs**

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository
{
    bool DeleteAll();
    bool DoesRecordExist(Guid id, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter);
    List<T> GetAll();
    T GetOne(Guid id);
    T Save(T item);
    bool Delete(Guid id);
    bool Delete(T item);
    IQueryable<T> Include(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

}

public interface IBaseRepository
{
    string CollectionName { get; }
}
```

Comment: is _commonRepository is a BaseRepository type?

Comment: @stinepike yeah, it shows that in the code example I believe

Comment: Why don't you just call _commonRepository.DoesRecordExist instead?

Comment: @stinepike right now i don't know how to define _commonRepository to call it

Comment: @Nkosi i made edits to the OP.  I do not know how I can actually access ICommonRepository atm... I provided the code on how I do it in my service with several other repos.  This is where I'm currently stuck.

Comment: "but i'm having issue referencing the ICommonRepository in the service" what issue? Could you please describe? And show us IBaseRepository

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I have added IBaseRepository code. I do not understand how to defined the ICommonRepository in the service, please look at the `GlobalService` code in my OP.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You need to specify the model. What is wrong with `ICommonRepository<User>`? Where `User` is class that inherited from `BaseClass` and represents your user entity

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I could define it as user but I want it to be generic.  So I want to be able to call the `DoesRecordExist` with User or Category or Subcategory.. etc

Comment: You will then need a factory that has a generic way to get the desired repository

Comment: You need to specify Model(table) where you are going to search if records exists. You should pass it explicit or create a factory as  Nkosi said

Comment: Hmm.... Ok.  Any good links/tutorials on how to make a generic factory since that seems to be next step ?

Comment: @tshoemake Having to rely on a factory or service locator anti-pattern does bring the quality of your design choices into question. This [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) may ultimately boil down to a design issue.

Comment: @tshoemake I would suggest moving away from a global data service and following a more explicit dependency principle in a more SOLID approach.

Comment: @Nkosi so do you mean something like a userservice for user, a categoryservice for category, etc ?

Comment: @tshoemake Something along that train of thought, yes. But not necessarily. inject only what is explicitly needed by the service. Keep it simple and only create what is needed.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot.  I'm testing your solution now.

Comment: @Nkosi how do i register this type in my global.asax `builder.RegisterType<CommonRepository<????>>().As<ICommonRepository<????>().AsImplementedInterfaces();`

Comment: what DI container are you using?

Comment: @Nkosi Autofac Container

Comment: something like `builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CommonRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(ICommonRepository<>))` Reference [Open Generic Components](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components)

Comment: Ah.. almost. I get this error `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type 'Project.Data.Repositories.CommonRepository`1' does not implement the interface 'Project.Data.Repositories.Interface.ICommonRepository`1'.';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191823/discussion-between-tshoemake-and-nkosi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will then need a factory that has a generic way to get the desired repository

```
public interface ICommonProvider {
    ICommonRepository<T> GetRepository<T>();
}

public class CommonProvider : ICommonProvider {
    private readonly ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope;

    public CommonProvider(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope) {
        this.lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }

    public ICommonRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() {
        return lifetimeScope.Resolve<ICommonRepository<T>>();
    }
}
```

that is registered at startup

```
builder.RegisterType<CommonProvider>().As<ICommonProvider>();
```

and inject that into the service

```
//...removed for brevity

private readonly ICommonProvider commonProvider;

public GlobalDataService(
    ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, 
    ISubcategoryRepository subCategoryRepository, 
    ISubcategoryDescriptionRepository subcategoryDescriptionRepository, 
    ICommonProvider commonProvider) {

    //...removed for brevity

    this.commonProvider = commonProvider;
}

public bool DoesUserRecordExist(Guid userId) {
    ICommonRepository<User> repository = commonProvider.GetRepository<User>();
    var existingData = repository.CommonDoesRecordExist(userId);
    if (existingData) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do other stuff
    }
}

//...
```

That said, I would suggest moving away from a global data service and follow explicit dependency principle in a more SOLID approach.

Simple example

```
public class UserService {
    private ICommonRepository<User> repository;

    public UserService(ICommonRepository<User> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public bool DoesUserRecordExist(Guid userId) {
        var existingData = repository.DoesRecordExist(userId);
        if (existingData) {
            //do stuff
        } else {
            //do other stuff
        }
    }        
}
```

and registered with your DI container something like

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(CommonRepository<>))
    .As(typeof(ICommonRepository<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Reference [Autofac: Registration Concepts - Open Generic Components](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly call the method of a child class using parent class reference. You need to cast `_commonRepository` to `CommonRepository`.

However, if `CommonDoesRecordExist` only returns `DoesRecordExist`, then why don't you just call `DoesRecordExist` directly.

Comment: I think my problem is right now _commonRepository doesn't have a definition in the service.  So I'm unable to reference any methods right now.

Comment: How can i call DoesRecordExist directly in my service??